# Registering a class for instantiating via Unsafe.allocateInstance in graalvm native image

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Graalvm native image of my application fails in runtime on the following method call:

```
Unsafe.allocateInstance(org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer.class);
```

with the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer is instantiated reflectively but was never registered. Register the class by using org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.RuntimeReflection
    at com.oracle.svm.core.graal.snippets.SubstrateAllocationSnippets.hubErrorStub(SubstrateAllocationSnippets.java:246)
```

Before generating the native image, I launched the application with `native-image-agent` and it generated the graalvm configuration jsons, but `reflect-config.json` had no entry for `org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer`.

Even if I add manually to `reflect-config.json`

```
{
  "name":"org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "allPublicConstructors" : true
  "allPublicFields": true,
  "allDeclaredMethods": true,
  "allPublicMethods": true
}
```

the native image still fails with the above-mentioned exception. Is there a way to make `Unsafe.allocateInstance` work in a native image?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it could help you at all. That class is very similar to 'CustomBuffer'. Try to add this configuration to your reflection.json and test if it works.

```
{
  "name" : "org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer",
  "fields":[
    {"name":"capacity", "allowUnsafeAccess":true}, 
    {"name":"container", "allowUnsafeAccess":true}, 
    {"name":"limit", "allowUnsafeAccess":true}, 
    {"name":"mark", "allowUnsafeAccess":true}, 
    {"name":"position", "allowUnsafeAccess":true}
  ]
}
```

I test it in my code and it works. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is `"unsafeAllocated": true` which you can set in `reflect-config.json`:

> Allows objects of this class to be allocated using `Unsafe.allocateInstance`

This was added by [this pull request](https://github.com/oracle/graal/pull/4393) and according to the Git tag seems to be available since GraalVM 22.1, though the documentation only seems to [mention it since version 22.2](https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/#specifying-reflection-metadata-in-json).